How to use unscoped CSS in light DOM
Has anyone succeeded adding an unscoped css (not a *.scoped.css file, but a regular *.css file) to a Light DOM LWC without receiving an error message?
According to Salesforce, this should be possible in most common environments, the exception being:

In Aura-based containers, light DOM components can only load scoped styles.

But in all my tests (LWC api version 61.0) I got this message in the Javascript console:

[LWC error]: Unscoped CSS is not supported in Light DOM in this environment. Please use scoped CSS (.scoped.css) instead of unscoped CSS (.css). See also: https://sfdc.co/scoped-styles-light-dom

And indeed, whenever I checked, the CSS was ignored.
I've tried lightning__AppPage, lightning__HomePage, lightning__Tab, lightning__RecordPage both on a Summer '24 scratch org and a Winter '24 Sandbox. Here are my test components:
outer.html
<template>
    <c-inner></c-inner>
</template>

inner.html
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
    <div>Hello World!</div>
</template>

inner.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Inner extends LightningElement {
    @api item;
    static renderMode = 'light';
}

inner.css
div {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

Have I misunderstood something?
